# Postgres returns list of datetime.date types that is not recognizable to .strftime

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

Trying to make a time series by pulling data from my postgres server. When I pull from the db, this is what is returned (eg.):

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 6, 3),), (datetime.date(2019, 6, 4),), (datetime.date(2019, 6, 5),)]
```

How would I take this list and make it recognizable to multiple different modules like pandas, statsmodels or datetime?
When I try to run it through most modules naturally I will get an error message like this.
Code:

```
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import statsmodels.formula as smf
    import psycopg2 as psy
    db = psy.connect(host='localhost', database='databistro', 
    user='admin', password='14055')
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT date_id FROM test_data;')
    date_db = cur.fetchall()
    date_strings = [datetime.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in date_db]
    print(date_db)
    db.close()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/PostgresTestData/PostgresTestData.py", line 21, in <module>
    date_strings = [datetime.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in date_db]
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/PostgresTestData/PostgresTestData.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
    date_strings = [datetime.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in date_db]
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

pls try

[d[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')   for d in date_db]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will work:

```
only_dates = [x for x,_ in date_db]
[d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d) for d in only_dates]
```

But I'm not sure why are you getting a tuple instead of a datetime from your select.

Comment: Because by default psycopg2 returns a list of tuples from a cursor: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html